# On an SSD, are there any advantages to a swap partition over a swap file?

Tags: swap, ssd

If my only "hard drive" is a smallish SSD, are there any advantages to setting up a swap partition rather than a swap file?

Comment: I don't even have a swap on my 80GB SSD as I've 8GB of RAM and do not need hibernation.

Comment: No swap here. my system is so quick booting I do not touch suspend and hibernation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no difference either way.

Comment: That's wrong. The kernel does support hibernating to a swap file. This works out of the box on some Ubuntu releases, others require manual tuning of the kernel command line in the bootloader configuration.

Comment: I am pretty sure it has never worked out of the box since it requires manually pointing the resume_offset boot parameter to the location of the file, but I guess that does work if you bother.  Answer corrected.

Comment: @psusi I know there is at least one hibernation framework on at least one Ubuntu version where you just issue the hibernate command and it takes care of setting up `resume_offset`. I don't remember which version that was, possibly 9.04 or 9.10 or 10.04, and I think the framework was `uswsusp` but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Gilles uswsusp is something you have to install yourself.  Out of the box Ubuntu has always just used the built in kernel implementation.

Comment: @punsi Thank you for your answer. Why would anyone choose a swap partition over a swap file, then, especially for smaller drives? What do you gain?

Comment: @Closure Cowboy you don't have to go through the trouble of configuring the boot parameters to be able to hibernate correctly.

Comment: In my opinion, Ubuntu should consider making a file rather than a partition the default. :) Thanks for the answer!